# Why does each person get assigned evrey option when I create a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has information about people:

```
Person ID, name,email,d.ob.
```

A second table that stores their job:

```
Job id, job role, salary.
```

I then created a table with foreign keys:

```
AdressId,Person Id, Jobid,Adress.
```

When i make the table every person is assigned each address that is avaiable and not one that was specfic to them?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Comment: Can you demonstrate how it shows currently and how you expect it to show? How do you know it is assigned? and 'Make' the table, not sure what this means as the tables should already be created at this point.

Comment: With _"...make the table..."_ do you mean you execute a SELECT query? If so then please add the code and also info about the adress table.